# Fractal set $E$ such that the indicator function $\mathbf{1}_E$ is BV

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory

Is there a "fractal" set $E \subset \mathbb R^2$ such that the indicator function $\mathbf{1}_E$ is in $BV(\mathbb R^2)$?

Answer (score 2):

An open subset $E$ of $\mathbb R^{N}$ such that $\mathbf 1_E$ belongs to $BV$ is said to be with "finite perimeter" and this implies that 
$$
\mathcal H^{N-1}(\partial E)<+\infty,
$$
where $\mathcal H^{N-1}$ stands for the $N-1$ Hausdorff measure. Gauss-Green formula holds true for such open sets.
As a result, we have in general 
$$
0<\mathcal H^{N-1}(\partial E)<+\infty,
\text{ which implies for $\epsilon >0$, } 
\mathcal H^{N-1+\epsilon}(\partial E)=0, \mathcal H^{N-1-\epsilon}(\partial E)=+\infty.
$$

Comment: I'm not sure what the last statement implies with respect to the question.